# Raciocínio lógico para a finalização de compras loja virtual

Tags: php

Desenvolvi uma loja virtual em PHP/Mysql do qual não uso sessões para armazenamentos dos produtos no carrinho e sim diretamente no banco de dados. O processo está fluindo normalmente: **Escolha do produto, Carrinho, Identificação, Local de entrega e Pagamento**.

O pagamento está sendo em módulo digital. Mercado Livre e Moip. O problema está quando chego no pagamento. Ao chegar nessa área, estou zerando o carrinho e mudando o status no banco de dados para **P**. Atualmente os status são: A = Aberto, P = Pagamento e F = Finalizado (após a confirmação de pagamento no retorno para a loja virtual no caso do cartão de crédito muda para **F**).

Só que me atentei a um detalhe. Quando o cliente está na parte de pagamento e a internet cair ou acabar a luz, ele terá que fazer novamente o processo de compra, sendo que o carrinho está vazio com o Status P e  com isso ao chegar novamente na parte de pagamento, acaba acumulando os valores e não criando uma nova compra. É exatamente aqui que não estou conseguindo achar um raciocínio lógico e preciso de ajuda nesse raciocínio.

Quando o cliente após passar pelos processos da loja virtual e chegar na parte do pagamento, como posso criar uma nova compra no caso do cliente querer retornar a loja ou acontecer algum problema externo sem acumular os valores das compras anteriores?

Comment: Acho que esse é um motivo de ter uma sessão ou um cookie.... Pq de alguma forma se tem de identificar esse cara de novo  para trazer os dados de onde ele parou...

Comment: Hum...se não quer acumular os valores, se tem de dar um reset caso não for finalizado....

Comment: Sessão tem, do ID dele quando ele se loga. Porém criei uma outra  sessão chamada SESSIONID, onde crio no momento em que o carrinho é criado e no pagamento deleto essa SESSIONID e crio uma nova no caso dele querer continuar comprando. Essa SESSIONID armazeno no banco de dados também. Vou ver se funciona dessa forma.

Comment: Você pode buscar a ultima compra com status P e colocar de volta no carrinho. Muitos e-Commerce utilizam assim, pelo que tenho visto na minha experiência de usuário.

Comment: É só recuperar os dados do banco e colocar de novo no carrinho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu particularmente utilizaria uma nova tabela:

```
pedidos
   id_user
   id_product
   ...
   status
```

pois assim, quando o usuário fizer login você verifica se ele possui um pedido com status pendente e coloca no carrinho dele os itens.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá teliz. Obrigado!